# Rendering Bezier expressions on Desmos and saving them as screenshots

Tags: node.js

I have the following code that takes a video, converts it to frames using ffmpeg, runs OpenCV Canny Edge on the frames and then converts the images to JSON files with Bezier curves.

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const potrace = require('potrace');
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const darkRed = chalk.hex('#b51b1b');

async function getCurveArray(file) {
    let curveArray = [];
    let paths;
    let x0;
    let x1;
    let x2;
    let x3;
    let y0;
    let y1;
    let y2;
    let y3;
    let trace = new potrace.Potrace();
    trace.loadImage(`./frames/${file}`, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        trace.getPathTag();
        paths = trace._pathlist;
        for (let h = 0; h < paths.length; h++) {
            x0 = paths[h].x0;
            y0 = paths[h].y0;
            for (let k = 0; k < paths[h].curve.n; k++) {
                let curveDataIndex = k * 3;
                if (paths[h].curve.tag[k] === 'CORNER') {
                    x1 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 1].x;
                    x2 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].x;
                    y1 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 1].y;
                    y2 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].y;
                    x0 = Math.round((x0 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    x1 = Math.round((x1 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    x2 = Math.round((x2 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y0 = Math.round((y0 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y1 = Math.round((y1 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y2 = Math.round((y2 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    curveArray.push(`((1-t)${x0}+t${x1}, (1-t)${y0}+t${y1})`);
                    curveArray.push(`((1-t)${x1}+t${x2}, (1-t)${y1}+t${y2})`);
                } else {
                    x1 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex].x;
                    x2 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 1].x;
                    x3 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].x;
                    y1 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex].y;
                    y2 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 1].y;
                    y3 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].y;
                    x0 = Math.round((x0 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    x1 = Math.round((x1 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    x2 = Math.round((x2 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    x3 = Math.round((x3 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y0 = Math.round((y0 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y1 = Math.round((y1 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y2 = Math.round((y2 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    y3 = Math.round((y3 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
                    curveArray.push(
                        `((1-t)((1-t)((1-t)${x0}+t${x1})+t((1-t)${x1}+t${x2}))+t((1-t)((1-t)${x1}+t${x2})+t((1-t)${x2}+t${x3})), (1-t)((1-t)((1-t)${y0}+t${y1})+t((1-t)${y1}+t${y2}))+t((1-t)((1-t)${y1}+t${y2})+t((1-t)${y2}+t${y3})))`
                    );
                }

                x0 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].x;
                y0 = paths[h].curve.c[curveDataIndex + 2].y;
            }
        }
        fs.writeFileSync(`./curves/curves_${file.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]}.json`, JSON.stringify(curveArray));
    });
}

function loadOpenCV() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        global.Module = {
            onRuntimeInitialized: resolve,
        };
        global.cv = require('./lib/opencv.js');
    });
}

function installDOM() {
    const dom = new JSDOM();
    global.document = dom.window.document;
    global.Image = Image;
    global.HTMLCanvasElement = Canvas;
    global.ImageData = ImageData;
    global.HTMLImageElement = Image;
}

function videoToFrames(fileName, extension) {
    let fileExtension = extension?.length > 1 ? extension : 'mp4';
    try {
        var process = new ffmpeg(`./video/${fileName}.${fileExtension}`);
        process.then(
            function (video) {
                video.fnExtractFrameToJPG('./frames', {
                    file_name: 'frame',
                    size: `?x480`,
                    frame_rate: 30,
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.code);
        console.log(e.msg);
    }
    console.log(darkRed('Video processed'));
    return 0;
}

async function cleanDirectories() {
    exec('rm -Force -r frames', { shell: 'powershell.exe' });
    exec('mkdir frames', { shell: 'powershell.exe' });
    exec('rm -Force -r curves', { shell: 'powershell.exe' });
    exec('mkdir curves', { shell: 'powershell.exe' });
}

videoToFrames('ganyu');

fs.readdir('frames', async function (err, files) {
    installDOM();
    await loadOpenCV();
    if (!files || files?.length == 0) {
        return console.log(darkRed('Frame directory was found empty or does not exist, attempt to rerun the program with the same parameters.'));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const image = await loadImage(`./frames/${files[i]}`);
        let src = cv.imread(image);
        cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        let src2 = new cv.Mat();
        cv.bilateralFilter(src, src2, 5, 50, 50, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT);
        let src3 = new cv.Mat();
        cv.rotate(src2, src3, cv.ROTATE_180);
        let dst = new cv.Mat();
        cv.Canny(src3, dst, 30, 200, 3, true);

        const canvas = createCanvas(300, 300);
        cv.imshow(canvas, dst);
        fs.writeFileSync(`./frames/${files[i]}`, canvas.toBuffer('image/jpeg'));
        src.delete();
        src2.delete();
        src3.delete();
        dst.delete();
        console.clear();
        console.log(darkRed(`${i + 1}/${files.length} frames prepared.`));
    }

    for (j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
        await getCurveArray(files[j]);
        console.clear();
        console.log(darkRed(`Frame ${j + 1}/${files.length} has been traced.`));
    }
});
```

My goal is to be able to render these frames individually in Desmos, capture the result and stitch the rendered frames back together into an .mp4.

My question is how should I even approach this? How could I render each frame, detect that its "finished" rendering and somehow save the image shown in the Desmos API?

I am also curious if there are any obvious ways I could decrease the quantity of the curves without severely damaging the quality of the frames outside of lowering the resolution in the ffmpeg function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desmos API `GraphingCalculator.asyncScreenshot()`

Waits for the current graph state to be fully evaluated, and allows for bounds to be passed the function easily cropping out anything unneeded.